# How to get body of response with reqwest?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm trying to send a GET request to the Binance API. But I'm getting this output in my terminal instead of the data:

```
Response { url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("api.binance.com")), port: None, path: "/api/v3/exchangeInfo", query: Some("symbol=BNBBTC"), fragment: None }, status: 200, headers: {"content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8", "content-length": "1515", "connection": "keep-alive", "date": "Thu, 23 Dec 2021 23:28:24 GMT", "server": "nginx", "vary": "Accept-Encoding", "x-mbx-uuid": "1244d760-2c41-46df-910f-b95c4a312bc2", "x-mbx-used-weight": "10", "x-mbx-used-weight-1m": "10", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self'", "x-content-security-policy": "default-src 'self'", "x-webkit-csp": "default-src 'self'", "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "pragma": "no-cache", "expires": "0", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS", "x-cache": "Miss from cloudfront", "via": "1.1 08b9c2fd11813ffdb8fa03129d0a465d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)", "x-amz-cf-pop": "FRA56-C2", "x-amz-cf-id": "EBp6UQUM3B2Lz0iAoPM88INjL4C0ugIgxmaoTPzi0Q4WPxfG46p8Yw=="} }
```

My code looks like this:

```
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();
    let res = client.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo?symbol=BNBBTC")
    // .header(USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36")
    // .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
    // .header(CACHE_CONTROL, "no-store")
    // .header(PRAGMA, "no-cache")
    .send().await;
    println!("{:?}", res.unwrap());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Printing the `Response` object [only shows a subset of the complete response](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/src/reqwest/async_impl/response.rs.html#392-400). You'd need to access the body of the response somehow, using `.json()` or similar.

Comment: Perfectly right.
Than you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html) that you're printing is basically just the initial HTTP info (e.g. status and headers). You'll need to wait for the payload as well using methods depending on what you're expecting:

- [`bytes`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes)/[`bytes_stream`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes_stream)/[`chunk`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.chunk) to get the raw data
- [`text`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text)/[`text_with_charset`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text_with_charset) to get the data as a string
- [`json`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json) with the `"json"` feature enabled to deserialize the data into a structured type. Ssee the docs for [`serde_json`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/) for more info.

In this case it looks like you're getting a JSON payload so using `.json()` into a deserializable type sounds like the right way to go, but if your only goal is to print it then `.text()` is probably the simpler approach.

```
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();
    let res = client
        .get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo?symbol=BNBBTC")
        .send()
        .await
        .expect("failed to get response")
        .text()
        .await
        .expect("failed to get payload");

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

Related:

- [Where is the body of a HTTP response stored? (with Rust + reqwest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956743/where-is-the-body-of-a-http-response-stored-with-rust-reqwest)

Comment: when the `.json` will return empty value?