# How to get body of response requested with authentication?

Tags: reqwest

When I try to get data from my elasticsearch API the following error appears:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to get response: reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("localhost")), port: Some(9200), path: "/part_of_speech", query: None, fragment: None }, source: hyper::Error(Connect, Error { code: -67843, message: "The certificate was not trusted." }) }', src/main.rs:15:10
```

---

No, not a duplicate of [How to get body of response with reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70468338/how-to-get-body-of-response-with-reqwest) since that one is not using authentication and the solution given did not work.

The following is the code from  which I expect the JSON output of the API

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
   let health = get_health().await;
}

async fn get_health() {
    let client = Client::new();
    let res = client
        .get("https://localhost:9200/speaker")
        .basic_auth("elastic", Some("7*7C68392TXAENxKRot"))
        .send()
        .await
        .expect("failed to get response")
        .text()
        .await
        .expect("failed to get payload");

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

What I have tried:

- I added the method `headers` but the same error appeared

  ```
    .headers(construct_headers())
      fn construct_headers() -> HeaderMap {
    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert(AUTHORIZATION, HeaderValue::from_static("Basic ZWxhc3RpYzo3KjdDYVJUcGliVFhBRU54S1JvdA=="));
    headers
  ```

  }